# Difference between "Need assistance?" and "Need an assistance"?

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles

Which is the correct way to write on a website and address my website's users?

1) Need **assistance**? Contact us by email...

or

2) Need **an assistance**? Contact us by email...

Comment: You don't use an article with *assistance* in this case.

Comment: Can you shorten to "Email us at..."?

Comment: Need some help?  Email us at...

Comment: [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/assistance) has many examples, including one with the collocation 'need assistance' and one with 'need any assistance', but _none_ with 'need an assistance'.  There may be confusion because the count noun 'assist' exists, often used in football and basketball.

Comment: Thank you for the answers!

Comment: A relatively uncommon usage is "an assist," but it's also a possibility for your purposes. "Need an assist? Email us."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assistance** is an uncountable noun. There is no such thing as "an assistance".

The confusion probably arises because "assistance" sounds like "assistant", which is a countable noun.

Comment: I've upvoted you but I don't entirely rule out the possibility of using it in a countable sense. Formerly, as the OED points out, it was often used in that way *1740   C. Cibber Apol. Life C. Cibber xvi. 322   Notwithstanding these assistances, the expence of every play amounted to fifty pounds.*

Comment: If I was writing a website in 1740 I would agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

We don't say *an assistance* because assistance is a *mass noun* like water, sand and air. We wouldn't normally say "Sip a water", "Mix a sand into that cement" or "Breathe in an air".

We do sometimes say "Do you want *any* assistance?" or "Do you want *some* assistance" because you can use 'some' and 'any' with mass nouns. It would be normal to ask "Do you want some water to drink?" or "Have you mixed any sand into that cement?"

Is it possible that you have mis-heard "Do you want any assistance?" as "Do you want an assistance?"

Comment: We don't normally say "sip a water". But it is perfectly possible to conceive of circumstances where one might. For example, if you were attending a water-tasting event for multiple types of spring water, someone might ask you to "sip a water, and then nibble a biscuit before you sip the next one". Equally if, let's say, some rescue organisation decided to use "assistance" in a countable way, I could think of far worse ways in which accepted English is corrupted on a daily basis.

Comment: @WS2 I agree that 'water' can be a countable noun,  'sand' and 'air' can also be countable ('an air' in particular can be a piece of music) which is why I said that we don't _normally_ say "a water" rather than _never_ say "a water". However seeing "Do you need an assistence?" as a prompt on a website would do nothing for the website's credibility with most native speakers.